# Remove an Operating System From my Dell Inspiron laptop

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

My laptop has two windows 7 on it with each one having its own account and password. For me to log on to another account, I have to shut down and move to another operating system. What can I do to have just one operating system?

Comment: Is what you are asking: Can I merge 2 windows 7 accounts from two different Windows 7 installations on the same machine?

Comment: Your title says "Can I format?", but your question doesn't ask about formatting. What are you trying to do, what your title asks or what your question asks?

Comment: Do you want to: move one account to the other os so that you can use them on the same os OR nuke everything on the hdd and do a clean install of Windows OR remove one installation of Windows and leave the other?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are speaking about two user profiles being listed at login. Check under Control Panel - User Accounts and see how many accounts are listed there. If there are two, remove one of them and you should just have one login going forward. Let me know.

Comment: **DON'T DO THIS BLINDLY!** It's *very* easy to revoke the only access to files by simply deleting a user account.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using EasyBCD software found free at http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1

Make sure that the OS you want to remove is located in a drive other than C. If you want to remove the OS which is installed on C then you need to move the boot loader of that OS you want to keep to the drive C using the above software

Answer (score 0):

**There are two ways :**

> first: from start menu search box type msconfig,then Enter,choose boot tab and delete the OS you want
>
> Second: use BCDEdit

The coming link will help you to do what you want : [How to Delete an Operating System Listed in Windows Boot Manager](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2288-windows-boot-manager-delete-listed-operating-system.html)